# Incrementing Letters in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I'm working with axlsx in rails and I want to be able to set up the columns according to the number of elements in a collection:

In my controller:

```
 @task_categories = TaskCategories.all
```

In my xlsx.axlsx view I would like to do something like:

```
 sheet.merge_cells("I2:#{'I'.next(@task_categories.count)}2")
```

but I get a no explicit conversion to Array error.

I can write a helper that loops the `.next` by `count`, but it seems that this is a common enough issue that there should be a built-in short-cut that I'm just missing.

**EDIT:**

I wrote a helper that works:

```
def increment_letter(l, c)
  (1..c).map { l = l.next }
  l
end
```

with the call:

```
 sheet.merge_cells("I2:#{increment_letter('I', @task_categories.count)}2")
```

But I am still looking for The Rails Way™.

Comment: It would help if you write which method is raising the error, and the full error message.

Comment: As it turns out, rails completely buggers which line the error is on when using axlsx views, so the array error was on another line.  Once I fixed that, I properly got the wrong number of arguments, 1 for 0 error.

Comment: I wrote a helper `def increment_letter(l, c)
  (1..c).map { l = l.next }
  l
end` that works, but I was looking for "The Rails Way™" to do it without the helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a quoting problem

```
"I2:#{'I'.next(@task_categories.count)}2"
```

Note my use of single quotes `'` around your `I`

Otherwise you could also use `%Q{...}` if that looks more readable to you

```
%Q{I2:#{"I".next(@task_categories.count)}2}
```

Lastly, `String#next` does not take arguments, so you'll end up with something like this

```
%Q{I2:#{"I".next}2} #=> "I2:J2"
```

Comment: [String#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-next) takes argument....whooaa.. It seems odd.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that just after I posted, and no, next does not take an argument. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand but something like this might do what you want:

```
first_col = "I"
last_col = first_col
@task_categories.count.times { last_col = last_col.next }
sheet.merge_cells("#{first_col}2:#{last_col}2")
```